# Java String Formatting not working as expected

Tags: java, string

please help me with the String formatting. 
I have a `String []`, and I am adding each String into a result String which will be displayed in `JOptionPane`. When I add each String into the result, I used `String.format("%-20s", String[i])` to make sure each string added to the final result have a minimum length of 20 and left justified. Every 5 words are started on a new line. However, the result shown in `JOptionPane` are not what I expected. The words are not aligned. Each word does not seem to have a minimum length of 20

```
private String keywordsList = "soup(s?)(base(s*))? hot(pot(s*))? "
        + "meat(s*) poultr((y)|(ies)){1} "
        + "beef(s?) cow(s?) ox(es)? bull(s?) "
        + "pork(s?) pig(s?) oink "
        + "mutton(s?) lamb(s?) sheep(s?) "
        + "chick(en(s)*)? hen(s)* rooster(s)* "
        + "seafood(s?) sea ocean shellfish fish((e)|(es))? "
        + "vegetable(s?) vege(s?) green plant(s?) veg(gies)? "
        + "signature(s?) recommendation(s?) recommend "
        + "h(i+) hell(o)+ y(o+) h(e)+(y) "
        + "morning afternoon evening "
        + "love(ly)? great good thank(s)? amazing excellent brilliant outstanding wonderful awesome okay "
        + "bad lousy useless stupid brainless fool(ish)? "
        + "got|get provide(s)* menu(s)* suppl(y|ies){1} offer(s*) "
        + "(good)?by(e+) leave end stop"; 

public String getKeywordList(){
    String [] keywordsListArray = this.keywordsList.split("\\s");
    String result = String.format("%-20s", keywordsListArray[0].replaceAll("[^a-z]", ""));
    for (int i = 1; i < keywordsListArray.length; i++){
        keywordsListArray[i] = keywordsListArray[i].replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
        if (i % 5 == 0){
            result += String.format("%n%-20s", keywordsListArray[i]);
        }
        else
            result += String.format("%-20s", keywordsListArray[i]); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: *Curious:* What is the point of `{1}`?

Comment: *"the result shown in JOptionPane are not what I expected"* What did you expect, and what did you get? Though, at a guess, it's because you're not using a [fixed-width font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).

Comment: {1} in regular expression specifies the number of occurrence of previous expression. In this case, I wanted 'y' or 'ies' to appear one time only

Comment: Which is exactly the same as not specifying `{1}`. In regex, the following are the same: `soup(s?)(base(s*))?` = `soups?(bases*)?`, `hot(pot(s*))?` = `hot(pots*)?`, `meat(s*)` = `meats*`, `poultr((y)|(ies)){1}` = `poultr(y|ies)`, etc. You have a very large number of unnecessary capture groups. Since you never care about the captures anyway, you should use non-capturing groups (`(?:x)`), to make it easier on the regex engine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yup, that is a lot of unnecessary coding

Comment: BTW: `meat(s*)`? That would match `meat`, `meats`, `meatss`, `meatsss`, `meatssss`, ... Is that really what you want? Perhaps you meant `meats?`, i.e. a single optional `s`. Same for a lot of the others, e.g. `menu(s)*`. And why do the same in a different way (`(s*)` vs `(s)*`)? *Consistency* is a good thing when writing code. It helps the human brain recognize patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first that result of getKeywordList() function is what you expect.

For example

```
  ...
  // print out for debug
  System.out.println(result);
  return result;
}
```

So you will get:

```
soupsbases          hotpots             meats               poultryies          beefs               
cows                oxes                bulls               porks               pigs                
oink                muttons             lambs               sheeps              chickens            
hens                roosters            seafoods            sea                 ocean               
shellfish           fishees             vegetables          veges               green               
plants              veggies             signatures          recommendations     recommend           
hi                  hello               yo                  hey                 morning             
afternoon           evening             lovely              great               good                
thanks              amazing             excellent           brilliant           outstanding         
wonderful           awesome             okay                bad                 lousy               
useless             stupid              brainless           foolish             gotget              
provides            menus               supplyies           offers              goodbye             
leave               end                 stop
```

If the result is what you expected, than your problem is with JOptionPane and might be you will need to replace spaces with &nbsp; and \n with <br/>

```
  return result.replaceAll(" ", "&nbsp;").replaceAll("\n", "<br/>");
```

btw: you will have to use monospaced font if you want to have a correct aligned columns ... so wrap result in <pre>...</pre> tags.

Comment: Oh my good, that is what I was expecting. So the problem is the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog();

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do primitive character-text-based alignment, but such a technique assumes the text is being rendered using a monospaced font. However the default font for `JOptionPane` is likely a proportionally-spaced font. But trying to set its font to something like Courier is likely the wrong idea, since that would ruin Swing's intended look and feel.  It's better to break out of text-based thinking, and think like a UI developer instead. What you really want is to arrange your keyword strings in the cells of a `JTable` component, and pass that as the `message` argument to the `JOptionPane`. The message doesn't have to be a `String` or `String []`. It can be a first-class nested component object.